# How to remove quote?

Tags: c#, regex, string, csv

I am trying to come up with the correct C# regex to remove unwanted quotes in a csv file. It can be word/numeric combination with quotes inside of a column.

Is there a simple `regex` to remove the quotes around the bold words. Only want the quotes removed.

```
"Testing","Test123", "**"Test0202**" else", "Test 223 **"testing**" end"
"Orange", "Banana", "**"apple**" crown", "tasty **"Grapes**" end"
```

I have tried to look at a few `regex` examples but couldn't figure out the exact pattern.

Currently, we are just looking for exact string matches to remove it.

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: also, instead of regexing around in your csv-file, i strongly recommend using an existing csv-parser instead, and then performing your operation on the individual fields.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ has a good playground

Comment: Indeed it is: https://regex101.com/r/aXjeHV/1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `(?<!, |,|^)"(?!,|$)` , see: https://regex101.com/r/aXjeHV/1

Selects all double quotes that are:

- not at the beginning of a line
- not at the end of a line
- not have a `,` after it
- not have a `,` before it, and do not have a `,`  (comma + space) before it.